# creating a type for custom object in typescript

Tags: typescript

I have an object that can be

```
var myObj = {
  "val1": { id: 1 }
  "val2": { id: 3}
}
```

So, I created type as:

```
type MyType = { id: number }
```

And then created another type for `myObj` as:

```
type CustomType = {
  [key: string] : MyType
}

var myObj: CustomType = {
  "val1": { id: 1 }
  "val2": { id: 3}
}
```

But this does not work and gives error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably defined `myObj` variable twice.

Also, you forget to put a comma after `{ id: 1 }`.

This should work

```js
type MyType = { id: number }

type CustomType = {
  [key: string]: MyType
}

var myObj: CustomType = {
  "val1": { id: 1 },
  "val2": { id: 3 }
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.4.0-beta#code/FAFwngDgpgBAsmAKpWBeGBvGBLAJgLhgDsBXAWwCMoAnGAX2FBRgGESBnEAezOWhnQZgMGAG0A1lDCFO1bEQDmAXUII%20UYA2AA3AIa0yYAPIUAVoTace6gZmEwARHoA2ARgeEseQq-oAaeyddZwAmD0wcAhgAZnpNYCA)

Answer (score 2):

That is because you try to use the same object `myObj`. You may need to define new object with **different name** like this:

```
var myObj = {
  "val1": { id: 1 },
  "val2": { id: 3}
}

type MyType = { id: number }


type CustomType = {
  [key: string] : MyType
}

var myObj1: CustomType = {
  "val1": { id: 1 },
  "val2": { id: 3}
}
```

[PlaygroundLink](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/G4QwTgBAtgng8gIwFYQLwQN4CgIQESgA2AjHgFyYQCWAJhcRAL4A0O%20RATOZbRQMyMsgrABcYABwCmEALIwAKhOnoM1OhAB2AVygJJkYaKUQAwloDOIgPZRFUtJjYBtANaSYFS2CoaA5gF0ICjk7SSEsLFBIWEQkYgozSxtQh2xcAhASblVeCAYWNgzCLgoc9QFwoA)